# Prove local minima in $x=0$ of a real function.

Tags: real-analysis

> Given $$f(x)=\begin{cases}
> x^2\sin(1/x) & \text{for } x \neq 0\\
> 0& \text{for } x = 0\\ 
> \end{cases}$$
>   How do I prove that $g(x)$ has a local minima in $x=0$ in the function $g(x) = f^2(x)$?

My professor introduced the definition for local maxima using epsilon but said that its analogous for the local minima. I don't understand how the definition for the local minima is.

Comment: Given ANY real valued function $f$ satisfying $f(0) = 0$, the function $g(x) = (f(x))^2$ will always have a local minimum at zero.

If you want $f^2(x) = f(f(x))$, then you should rephrase your question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do first is to know the definition of a local minimum (which you indicate that you don't).

> A function $\phi(x)$ has a local minima at $a$ if there's a $\epsilon>0$ such that $|x-a|<\epsilon$ implies that $\phi(x)\ge\phi(a)$

Now we have that $g(x)=[f(x)]^2\ge 0$ which means that $g(0)=0$ and thereby the definition for local minimum is fulfilled.

Actually in this case you don't have to call it local since it also fulfils the definition of a global minima:

> A function $\phi(x)$ has a (global) minima at $a$ if for all $x$ we have that $\phi(x)\ge \phi(a)$.

Comment: Thanks, but i think that i can't just say that it is even a global minimum. I will need to prove that $f(x) >= f(a)$ or that $f^2(x) >= 0$.

Comment: @Razmo $g(x)=f^2(x)$ means $g(x)=[f(x)]^2$. Squares are never negative in real analysis...

Answer (score 0):

Hint. Read the definition of local minimum point [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxima_and_minima#Definition) then note that $g(x):=f^2(x)\geq 0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $g(0)=0$.

Comment: @Surb No, I get $g(3\pi/2) = 9\pi^2\sin^2(2/3\pi)/4\ge 0$